# Returning a tuple containing the arithmetic mean and the unbiased sample variance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a function which takes a list of numbers of length ≥2, and returns a tuple containing the arithmetic mean and the unbiased sample variance of those numbers. i.e. given a list of items [1,2,…,], return a tuple (,2) where:

[image]

**I'm not allowed to use inbuilt functions like sum, any math functions, etc.** I'm not sure how to proceed without using those functions.

My code:

```
def mean_variance(numbers):
    m = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
    var = sum((xi - m) ** 2 for xi in numbers) / len(numbers)
    return m, var
```

What I'm testing on:

```
assert(mean_variance([1, 2, 3]) == (2, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you arent allowed to use inbuilt functions, but I guess you can do it without inbuilt functions like this:

```py
def mean_variance(numbers):
    meanSum = 0
    for num in numbers:
        meanSum += num
    mean = meanSum / len(numbers)

    varSum = 0
    for num in numbers:
        varSum += (num - mean) ** 2
    var = varSum / (len(numbers) - 1)

    return mean, var
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `sum` function with `reduce` and corrected an error in the formula.
Here is the code:

```
from functools import reduce


def mean_variance(numbers):
    m = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, numbers) / len(numbers)
    var = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, ((xi - m) ** 2 for xi in numbers)) / (len(numbers)-1)
    return m, var
```

Comment: would importing reduce be considered using inbuilt functions?

Comment: It is a buitin function, but is not related to math. U can use to do whatever u want. In this case I used it to sum. If u want, you can use a `for loop` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any **inbuilt** methods

Mean and variance can come as floats.
so returning `int` or `float` will be automatically handled by `assert`

```
def mean_variance(inputList):
  sum = 0
  lenList = 0
  for val in inputList:
    sum = int(val) + sum
    lenList = lenList + 1
  mean = sum/lenList

  sum_sq = 0
  for val in inputList:
    sq = (int(val) - int(mean)) ** 2
    sum_sq = sum_sq + sq
  variance = sum_sq/(lenList-1)

  return (float(mean), float(variance))


print(mean_variance([1, 2, 3]))
assert mean_variance([1, 2, 3]) == (2, 1)
```